# Can you override Product.tags in Shopify?

Tags: filter, shopify, liquid

Apologies ahead of time; still pretty new to CS.

I'm adding a filter to my store that allows customers to filter via "InStock" and "PreOrder" tags. I want these tags to be added and removed automatically as stock fluctuates. Some items are sold in store only, and will not be display (hence the check for a "nocart" tag). Here's the related liquid code:

```
{% assign currenttags = product.tags | join: ', ' %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if product.tags contains "nocart"%}{% break %}{% endif %}
    {% if variant.inventory_quantity == 0 and variant.inventory_policy == "continue" %}
        {% assign currenttags = currenttags | remove: ", InStock" %} 
        {% assign currenttags = currenttags | append: ", PreOrder" %}
    {% elsif variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
        {% assign currenttags = currenttags | remove: ", PreOrder" %}
        {% assign currenttags = currenttags | append: ", InStock" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{ currenttags | split: ', '}}
{% assign product.tags = currenttags %}
{{product.tags}}
```

As you can probably tell, I want to use the in-built tag filter to display this, which relies on crawling `product.tags`.

I tried outputting currenttags, then product.tags after assigning it to the currenttags array. Result is "xxx xxx xxx xxx Preorder" (currenttags)
"xxx xxx xxx xxx" (product.tags)

Can `product.tags` be overridden? Is there a better way to filter based on stock levels + product status? Thanks!

Edit: Looking further into the docs, I'm pretty sure `product.tags` just returns tag values, not the reference. Thinking I need to connect to the Admin API and access product tags from that. Oof!

Answer (score 0):

Liquid is only an templating language, this means that it's meant to mainly output data and modify it on the front-end said, so that means that it doesn't have the ability to modify any of the back-end entries like in this case `tags`.

In order to achieve what you are asking you will need to create a custom App that will tie on specific webhook (example order create or product update depending on when you modify the stock) and update the tags via the API.

There might be ready to use Apps for this but you will need to look into this on your own

Answer (score 0):

Tags can't be modified through liquid front end code.

Why use tags for this at all (it's a hack for what is already available via `inventory_quantity`) ?  I suggest using the inventory count at all times and you won't have to manage tags.

If you really want to have this happen automatically, consider using shopify flow app, as it is a BACKEND app and allows you to modify tags based on triggers you create, and can be set to run after each order completes.

Overall, if you're trying to adjust what the users sees, just use logic based off of `inventory_quantity` and not tags.

Comment: Honestly, I'm using inventory to manipulate tags just to be able to use tag filtering rather than creating my own filter based off inventory.

Going strictly off inventory, like you said, is the most efficient way. I'll take a look into creating custom filters. Do you, by chance, know of any resources related to this? Thanks!

Comment: You bet: This https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects and this https://shopify.github.io/liquid/